# dynamic content load in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

this is my first jquery code.Here i am trying to do a content loading mechanism using jquery ajax. It supposed to load content in a container div.But it is navigating me to a whole new page.I want that the 'a' tag does not navigate me to another page.What i am doing wrong here ?How i can achieve that?

```
<html>

<body>
<ul>
<li><a href='about.html'>about</a></li>
<li><a href='faq.html'>faq</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='content'></div>
<script src='c/xampp/htdocs/practice/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$('a').click(function(){
       var page=$(this).attr('href');
       $('#content').load(page);
       return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `c/xampp/htdocs/practice/jquery/jquery.js` should be `c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/jquery/jquery.js` assuming you are on a windows machine

Comment: changing path name didn't work. :( may be a problem in my jquery.js file

Comment: If you're having trouble with getting your jQuery file to load, you could always use a CDN instead, such as https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js Just copy the **full** link into the <script> tag's src attribute.

Comment: adding type attribute inside script tag solved my problem. what a silly mistake :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are clicking on a link which should take you to the page before you do anything. Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent this.

```
$('a').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       var page=$(this).attr('href');
       $('#content').load(page);
       return false;
});
```

Also you should include jQuery using your localhost url : (I guess you are using proper link for the page?)

```
 <script src='http://localhost/practice/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
```

Remember, `type="text/javascript"` definition is not necessary in html5. But you didn't use the html5 doctype definition. Use this at the top of everything in the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: still doesn't work .i have used an alert inside the function.It haven't triggered . I assume there is a problem in my jquery download file.  :(

Comment: Check the edited part of my answer. Looks like you haven't included the jQuery properly.

Comment: do i need to use http here ?

Comment: adding type='text/javascript' attribute in script tage made it work :/ :))

Comment: Hm. That is actually not necessary for html5. But I know now why it didn't work. You didn't include doctype definition in the beginning. I will just edit my answer to add that. Otherwise you may have miss more features of html5.